# built-in function to return the argument itself

Tags: functions

The line below shows the first element which is not `nil`.

```lisp
(message "%s" (cl-some  #'(lambda (x) x) '(nil nil "hello" nil)))
;; Output: hello
```

Is there a built-in function which is equivalent to `(lambda (x) x)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`identity` is a built-in function that returns its argument unchanged:

```
(identity ARG)
```

Comment: Thanks. What should I do to find a built-in function easily? I searched a lot but could not find it.

Comment: I don't know of any magic formula for finding such things, but in this case, it's helpful if you know other functional programming languages as well, as it's common for them to support some sort of an identity function.

Comment: To discover the existence of a function you can match either its doc or its name. Matching the doc means you can sometimes use words that might be used to describe the function. The apropos commands are your friend. See, e.g., `apropos` and `apropos-documentation`. For this function, "identity" is the typical name and describer, AFAIK.